# Android developer new to ListFragment

Tags: android

So I am sure there is a simple explanation to why this isn't working, but I don't know what it is.  I've tried all of the obvious things.  Seen several demos and tweaked my code to fit them.  I simply cannot get this ListFragement to show.  Can someone tell what I am doing wrong? Or do I need to give more details?

Here is my fragment:

```
public class BlankFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static final String[] items = {
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"
    };

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            items));
    }
}
```

Here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                android.R.id.content, new BlankFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

From what I am reading something this simple should work.  But it doesn't.  Everything compiles and runs but the activity is just blank.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youhou, got it was f****g more complicated than what I was thinking: the problem was that you're mixing `Fragment`with `Fragment` (welcome in Android): your `ActionBarActivity` comes, as you maybe know from a support library the v7 and the fragment you were using were from normal lib and what happened was that you used the "false" `FragmentManager`: you called `getFragmentManager`instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`but it's quite amazing that it compiles (a lot much more to understand then. Whatever, this code works:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

// @author: Laurent Meyer

public class SoMain extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_so);
        FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fm.add(android.R.id.content, new BlankFragment()).commit();


}

public static class BlankFragment extends ListFragment {
    private final String[] items = {
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"
    };

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        setListAdapter(aa);
    }

}
}
```

It was so weird that I needed to create a new blank project!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks!  Your answer did help but maybe in a different way.  So I realized that the ActionActivityBar was not needed and started to look at other choices.  If you don't want to support older builds (like API 16 and up) you can omit the ActionActivityBar and just use Activity.  Then it seems the rest of it is in the manifest.  Anyway I got it to work and you got me in the right direction. :)  Hopefully the code will be useful to someone else. :)

Comment: yes it is useful to me, cause now i will try and guess, how it happened and why it happened how it happened. but if the code really really solved your problem you can always accept it sir, unless it was not  to your satisfaction @BynaryShef

Comment: I think it solved your problem and was what you needed so feel free to accept it to set it as solved and it will show to user people having the same problem how to solve it. :)

Comment: I just did.  I don't have the ability to upvote yet but do have the ability to set it as answered.